# OpenERP Reports Creation for Beginners

Tags: python, xml, report, odoo

I'm going to create reports for my module from OpenERP 7. as per forums i used **Web kit Report** method.

first, from using below command i installed wkhtmltopdf on my machine.

```
sudo apt-get install wkhtmltopdf
```

its installed. now when i type in terminal its show location path also.

```
$ which wkhtmltopdf
/usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf
```

I'm installed Web kit Report module in OpenERP 7.then how to start report create process.?
is there any tutorial,blog,post,video to follow ?
or can any one please tell me steps for that.

thanks

Answer (score 2):

For OpenERP v7 you need to set the **webkit path** in the system parameter

go to `Settings > Technical > Parameter > System Parameter`

create a new record with key: `webkit_path`

and value will be the path of webkit executable.

for report sample you can check the code of `report_webkit_sample` module of OpenERP v6.1 Addons. There is no difference in the code.

This [Slides](http://www.slideshare.net/OpenERP2011_CommunityDays/camptocamp-webkit) will helps you.

Answer (score 1):

For webkit report you have create **.mako** file instead of **.rml**, one **parsing py** file and register your report in xml same as you do with rml report.

You can have some more information about [Webkit report modules & configuration.](http://help.openerp.com/question/4724/how-to-configure-webkit-for-v7/)
Just look at other webkit reports and you will come to know how to deal with it.